# How do I append data to memcached using Enyim.Caching in C#?

Tags: c#, memcached, enyim.caching

I am trying to append data to memcached using C# Enyim.Caching but it forces me to send data as ArraySegment

```
public bool Append(string key, ArraySegment<byte> data);
```

How do I convert a string or array of strings to ArraySegment ?

Is there a better way to use Append?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out how to do this.
In order to convert a string to `ArraySegment<byte>` use the following code.

```
byte[] arrByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
ArraySegment<byte> data = new ArraySegment<byte>(arrByte, 0, arrByte.Length);
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: What format does it come back in when you use 'get'? Is it simply a byte array?  If so, how did you get that back to string?  Curious because I'm trying all the usual ways and it's not working.